# POST request via HttpClient.PostAsync with StorageFile inside body (WinRT)

Tags: c#, post, uwp, windows-runtime

I need create `POST` request from WinRT app,which should contain `StorageFile`.
I need to do this exactly in style like this : post request with file inside body.
Is it possible? I know about `HttpClient.PostAsync(..)`, but I can't put `StorageFile` inside request body. I want to send `mp3` file to `Web Api`

On server side I get file like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage UploadRecord([FromUri]string filename)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Audio/" + filename + ".mp3");
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                }
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            }
            else
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as a `byte[]` using the `ByteArrayContent` class as a second parameter:

```
StroageFile file = // Get file here..
byte[] fileBytes = null;
using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
    }
}

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

await httpClient.PostAsync(address, fileBytes);
```

Comment: Hi,Yuval. HttpClient dont have overload with ByteArrayContent.

Comment: thank you, but it not helped, I added server side code for example how I get file from request.

Comment: It didn't help because your server side code is reading files the wrong way. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543150/httprequest-files-is-empty-when-posting-file-through-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading files of any appreciable size, then it's best to use the Background Transfer API so that the upload doesn't get paused if the app is suspended. Specifically see [BackgroundUploader.CreateUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701127.aspx) which takes a StorageFile directly. Refer to the [Background Transfer sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61) for both the client and server sides of this relationship, as the sample also includes a sample server.

Comment: Hi,I tried running this example, but something strange with this it. Example always stopped work on line `UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);`
Sad, but I dont know why it happening and server side work great...

Comment: Don't know why that would be happening (it's not an async call either). I can only think that perhaps the file is corrupt or something.

Answer (score 0):

To use less memory you can pipe the file stream to the `HttpClient` stream directly.

```
    public async Task UploadBinaryAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file == null)
            return;
        using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var content = new HttpStreamContent(fileStream);
                content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                _ = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions appropriately
            }
        }
    }
```