# HttpURLConnection "enctype" POST

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, enctype

When building a html form with post method you can specify the "enctype" attribute. Is there a way to do that with HttpURLConnection POST method?

Comment: I am not sure if enctype and content-type are the same thing.

Comment: It is, see eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339770/whats-the-difference-between-content-type-and-enctype