# NodeJS/Express: How to get enctype of submitted form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, web

If you POST an HTML form with an enctype attribute (for example enctype=multipart/form-data) and it gets submitted to an Express Route, how can you access that enctype value from the route or from middleware? I'm on Express 4.x.

Comment: I think it should be in headers so check req.headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `enctype` attribute on a form, the browser sends it as `content-type` in the request ([see this SO question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339770/whats-the-difference-between-content-type-and-enctype)). In Express, you can access the `content-type` header name from the request object like this: `req.headers['content-type']`.